# Delete entire section in list

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm creating a list that consists of a section and for each section I'm creating these nested rows. I'd like to be able to delete both the nested rows and the section rows when swiping left. However, I can only swipe left on the nested rows, not the sections. Is this possible?

```
        List {
            ForEach(self.items) { headerItem in
                Section(header: HeaderView(item: headerItem).onTapGesture {
                }, footer: EmptyView()) {
                    ForEach(headerItem.versions) { version in
                        SubHeaderView(version: version)
                        .onTapGesture {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                print("TEST DELETE1")
            })
        }
```

[image: Swipe left example]

Answer (score 0):

You can't using the build in API. But you could add that to your HeaderView - place the delete button in a ZStack under your view in HeaderView, and use a drag GestureRecognizer to modify the offset that view.

Comment: It should. If you have a hierarchy, try using DisclosureGroup or OutlineGroup and apply the same strategy on the label of said DisclosureGroup.